# Unix Script, problem with a 2d array

Tags: bash, shell-script, array, for

I have 2 arrays that refer to files for example

```
alpha=file 1
beta=file2
Charlie=file3
delta=file4
beta2=file5
beta3=file6
Charlie2=file7
charlie3=file8
delta2=file9
delta3=file10

array1=("$alpha" "$beta" "$Charlie" "$delta)
array2=("$beta2" "$beta3" "$Charlie2" "$Charlie3" "$delta1 "$delta3")
```

Then I have an algorithm that goes through and uses these files together example

```
for ((i=0;2;i++))
do
   for((j=0;2;j++))
   do
     ./${array1[$i]}.sh ${array2[$j]}.in        
   done
done
```

Problem is I would like the array1 and array 2 to correspond such that

it would be for example

```
./file2.sh file5.in
```

But I can never get it to do it because of course when j resets for each loop of i. What is the solution for this?

Comment: bash is not an ideal language for using 2d arrays. Choose other language for your project.

Comment: Is there a better way to do this in bash. I have no option other to use bash at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

If you want the 1st item of array1 to correspond to the 1st item of array2, then you don't need nested loops: just use the same index variable

```
for i in {0..2}; do
    "./${array1[i]}.sh" "${array2[i]}.in"
    # ..........^.................^
done
```

Or, use an associative array:

```
declare -A map=(
    [$alpha]=$beta2
    [$beta]=$beta3
    [$Charlie]=$Charlie2
    [$delta]=$Charlie3
)

for key in "${!map[@]}"; do
    do_something_with "$key" and "${map[$key]}"
done
```

Comment: There's no guarantee about the *order* of the keys in the `for` loop for an associative array.

Comment: I think I have got round the issue by getting rid of the nested loops and made array 1 same size as array 2 by repeating the declarations for each element of array 2. This seems to work!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want an array zipping operator, then `zsh` may be a better option than `bash` here:

```
$ a=({A..D}) b=({1..10})
$ for i j (${a:^b}) echo $i $j
A 1
B 2
C 3
D 4
$ for i j (${a:^^b}) echo $i $j
A 1
B 2
C 3
D 4
A 5
B 6
C 7
D 8
A 9
B 10
```

`${a:^b}` and `${a:^^b}` are two array *zipping* [parameter expansion](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion) operators. The difference is seen when one array has fewer elements than the other, in which case the latter will reuse the elements from the shorter one to match the larger one.

Note that leaving a variable unquoted in `zsh` doesn't have the same nasty side effects as in other Bourne-like shells, but still removes empty elements. So, if your arrays may contain empty elements, you would need to write it:

```
for i j ("${(@)a:^^b}") echo "$i" "$j"
```